# Can you remove the GNOME classic or Gnome desktop option from the startup screen?

Tags: gnome, 22.04, gui, software-uninstall, metapackages

A while back I installed a desktop metapackage for gnome or gnome vanilla. I don't remember which one I installed however I have included a picture of what I'm looking to remove. This picture is a close up of the lower left hand corner of the screen after you click on the gear icon. Is it possible to remove the Gnome options or are they best left alone? I'm using Ubuntu 22.04 LTS.

I was able to find this using the command `view /var/log/apt/history.log`. I think the package was called vanilla-gnome-desktop.

```
Start-Date: 2023-06-11  18:10:52
Commandline: apt autoremove
Requested-By: chase (1000)
Remove: libntfs-3g89:amd64 (1:2021.8.22-3ubuntu1.2)
End-Date: 2023-06-11  18:10:52

Start-Date: 2023-06-11  18:13:16
Commandline: apt remove vanilla-gnome-desktop
Requested-By: chase (1000)
Remove: vanilla-gnome-desktop:amd64 (0.92)
End-Date: 2023-06-11  18:13:16

Start-Date: 2023-06-11  18:22:26
Commandline: apt install vanilla-gnome-desktop
Requested-By: chase (1000)
Install: vanilla-gnome-desktop:amd64 (0.92)
End-Date: 2023-06-11  18:22:26
```

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: It's unclear which release of Ubuntu you are referring to.

Comment: If I'd forgotten what package I'd installed; I'd just view the system logs to see what I actually installed & when (*hopefully you'll know roughly when; be it recent, weeks ago, or months ago as the more you recall the easier it is*).  Have you looked?  I'd use `view /var/log/apt/history.log` & just paste/search using normal POSIX type commands

Comment: @guiverc I just used the command you gave me and it definitely helped me fine the package. I've updated the post with what I found. I looks like I already tried to uninstall it but failed.

Comment: `dpkg -S /usr/share/xsessions/` gives an overview.

Answer (score 0):

The desktop files for different sessions are stored under the folder

```
/usr/share/xsessions/
```

you can use dpkg to filter for the relevant packages.

```
dpkg -S /usr/share/xsessions/*
```

But be careful what you purge.

Make a simulation first; and look what would be removed.

Comment: The response I got from your dpkg -S command was "gnome-shell-extensions, gnome-session, ubuntu-session: /usr/share/xsessions". I'm not sure what that tells me but I'm guessing that in order to remove the gnome classic icon in the screenshot I need to remove a desktop session?