# How do I purge Gnome desktop on a Ubuntu Desktop minimal installation with LXDE installed?

Tags: gnome, 22.04, desktop-environments, lxde

After having installed [LXDE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LXDE) with `apt install lxde`, I proceeded to remove Gnome Desktop Environment. To my astonisment, after running `apt purge -y gnome gnome-core` I get the output that `Package gnome is not installed, so not removed.` and `Package gnome-core is not installed, so not removed.` Having read some of the comments I even ventured `apt purge ubuntu-desktop` and got `Package ubuntu-desktop is not installed, so not removed.` Yet, when rebooting I am still presented with the option `Ubuntu Default`, which after logging in looks like my old Gnome Desktop Environment.
[The content of my](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1475421/can-you-remove-the-gnome-classic-or-gnome-desktop-option-from-the-startup-screen) `/usr/share/xsessions/` was `LXDE.desktop openbox.desktop ubuntu-xorg.desktop ubuntu.desktop` . After removing `openbox.desktop ubuntu-xorg.desktop ubuntu.desktop` from `/usr/share/xsessions/`, I'm still presented with `Ubuntu (default)` and `Ubuntu on Wayland` options, and when I choose the option of `Ubuntu (default)` I get logged in to my old Gnome Desktop Environment.

About me:
Using Ubuntu Desktop 22.04 LTS minimal installation, freshly installed. I know that it sound like a better idea to just
install Ubuntu Server with LXDE but that is not convenient to me because I have a damaged ethernet interface on my laptop. I find it very convenient that sound on Ubuntu Desktop just works without the need of tinkering too much. That was not my experience after installing Ubuntu Server on my laptop. Let us then limit the scope of this question to the solutions that include only Ubuntu Desktop.

My queestions:

**1.** Was `gnome-core` ever installed on my system? How is it possible to log in to Gnome Desktop Environment and not have this package installed?

**2.** How do I uninstall Gnome Desktop Environment?

**3.** How do I remove all desktop environment log in options other than LXDE?

P.S. Please do not mark as a duplicate?

Comment: Just FYI:  But you do realize the `openbox` session was installed by you when you installed LXDE. The LXDE desktop doesn't include a WM and Lubuntu used `openbox` for this purpose.  The `openbox` session was just an option to let you use a WM only (ie. a lighter option than using the LXDE interface which includes LXDE + WM)  GNOME or Ubuntu Desktop uses a different WM.

Comment: @sudodus I've modified my question in response to your comments. This comment I'll delete soon in order to avoid cluttering.

Comment: If you installed Ubuntu Desktop originally; why not just `sudo apt remove ubuntu-desktop`, even use the *purge* option if you wish. Your approach makes little sense to me (*don't forget LXDE is now upstream Debian packaged; some defaults differ to 18.04 or earlier*)  Providing the specific package/command used to install LXDE would have been more useful than a link to wikipedia.

Comment: Let me illuminate the fact that installing Ubuntu with GNOME and then purging it is a very bad idea. Ubuntu uses a modified version of GNOME known as Ubuntu-Desktop, which somewhat resembles to Unity desktop. If you want to use LXDE environment, you should install Lubuntu or some other flavour of Ubuntu that comes with that desktop environment by default.

Comment: @Error404 Lubuntu hasn't used LXDE for [ten releases now](https://lubuntu.me/lunar-released/) (*not counting respins of LTS releases too*), so using a Lubuntu base (ie. LXQt desktop & Qt5 libraries/toolkits) won't be any closer than Ubuntu Desktop (GNOME + GTK4 libraries/toolkits) as both differ to the older/deprecated GTK2 used by LXDE.

Comment: @guiverc I installed LXDE with `apt install lxde`. Modified my question in response to your comment.

Comment: @Error404 `apt purge ubuntu-desktop` gave me `Package ubuntu-desktop` is not installed, so not removed.` I've just added this information to the question.

Comment: You've not mentioned the `apt remove ubuntu-desktop` seems that seems to me to be exactly what you're asking for, yet skipped that part of my comment.  Yes I don't fully understand what you're trying to do, as you mention desktops; yet removed openbox WM option (openbox is a WM or *window manager* and not a desktop); are you intending to switch to `xfwm4` as used by Xfce desktop instead of openbox? or don't understand the terms you're using completely?  (LXDE isn't complete & requires other components to function, Debian uses packages from Xfce, Lubuntu used `openbox` etc)

Comment: Try `ubuntu-desktop-minimal` then if that's what you installed; the packages included on the Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS desktop ISO can be viewed by looking at the manifest - https://releases.ubuntu.com/22.04/ubuntu-22.04.3-desktop-amd64.manifest (*or other ways too; installed systems vary depending on options selected at install*)

Comment: @guiverc Saddly, `apt purge ubuntu-desktop-minimal` gave me `Package ubuntu-desktop-minimal is not installed, so not removed.`

Comment: It is known to be difficult [when you have two desktop environments] to completely remove one desktop environment without damage to the remaining one (in your case to remove the default one and keep a good LXDE). If you can accept the extra drive space occupied by the default Gnome, just keep it. I think LXDE will work. There will be some double tools in the menus, but I think you can live with that.

Comment: @guiverc I installed LXDE and it works fine with its default window manager (I don't kknow which WM it is but certainly not a tiling one). Now, I just want to remove the bloat, i.e. GNOME desktop or whatever there is in Ubuntu 22.04, that I'm not going to use. I want LXDE to be the only option.

Comment: I think you're after only a LXDE *session* to be offered at login, ie. not desktop/WM but want a LXDE session (which includes the LXDE desktop + WM selected by `lxsession` etc); Fair enough.  I did some LXDE QA at 22.04 (*jammy*) but can't recall what your starting point includes (ie. minimal Ubuntu Desktop install) as my testing used a Lubuntu install AND Xubuntu install as base, and I used full installs (*I find them easier to work with & remove; as minimal install installs everything then removes parts - to me easier to have a known starting point; ie. the -desktop package*)

Comment: List for yourself (not us) what packages you have installed now: `apt list --installed`. Review the list for gnome-related packages (grep "gnome", for example).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Open a terminal

Update repositories

```
sudo apt update
```

Install aptitude and deborphan

```
sudo apt install --reinstall aptitude deborphan
```

Eliminate the components of gnome that are not necessary in lubuntu

```
sudo aptitude remove '?and(?reverse-depends(gnome),?not(?reverse-depends(?exact-name(lubuntu-desktop))))'
```

Reinstall lubuntu-desktop

```
sudo apt install --reinstall lubuntu-desktop
```

Eliminate orphan packages

```
sudo deborphan

sudo apt --purge remove $(deborphan)

sudo deborphan --libdevel

sudo apt --purge remove $(deborphan --libdevel)

sudo deborphan --find-config

sudo dpkg --purge $(deborphan --find-config)
```

Remove unnecessary packages

```
sudo apt autoremove
```

Remove downloaded packages

```
sudo apt clean
```

Restart system

```
sudo reboot
```